# How to use automatic thread management for implementing producer/consumer in Java

Tags: java, executorservice, producer-consumer

I need to implement a producer / consumer scheme, where consumers, for performance reasons, try to process many work items in one batch (each of them drains the work queue).

At the moment I'm just creating a fixed number of identical workers which work on the same queue in a loop. As some of them may die, I need to take care of replacing them.

I would love to use a fixedThreadPool to manage thread replacement, but my case doesn't map to `Executor` scheme, as the desired granularities of the producer and consumers don't match -- only the consumers can collect suitable batch of work.

What are my options of managing a (fixed size) thread pool, when my work items can't be expressed as Runnables/Callables?

(Alternatively, can I somehow keep my requirement of batching produced work items together and still be able to use Executor service?)

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to have producers/consumers as `Runnable`s and use `BlockingQueue` to communicate any data between.

For example, here is a simplistic implementation of producers, that generate `String` items to the `queue`, and consumers that read the items in batches:

```
class ProducerConsumerPing {
    private static final class PingProducer implements Runnable {
        private final BlockingQueue<String> queue;

        PingProducer(BlockingQueue<String> queue) {
            this.queue = queue;
        }

        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                queue.offer("ping");
            }
        }
    }

    private static final class PingConsumer implements Runnable {

        private final BlockingQueue<String> queue;
        private final int batchSize;

        PingConsumer(BlockingQueue<String> queue, int batchSize) {
            this.queue = queue;
            this.batchSize = batchSize;
        }

        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                List<String> batch = new ArrayList<>();
                queue.drainTo(batch, batchSize);
                System.out.println("Consumed: " + batch);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ExecutorService producers = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        ExecutorService consumers = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        BlockingQueue<String> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            producers.submit(new PingProducer(queue));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            consumers.submit(new PingConsumer(queue, 10));
        }

        producers.shutdown();
        producers.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        consumers.shutdown();
        consumers.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

Notes:

- In the example I use `String` as `work items`, but of course you can put any `Object` to the queue
- Consumer batching is achieved by using [BlockingQueue.drainTo(Collection, int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#drainTo-java.util.Collection-int-)

Comment: Thanks! This would solve the batching part, but I'm still missing automatic thread management.

Comment: You're welcome! Glad to help you! Btw, in the example threads are managed by `ExecutorService`. Just curious, if not `ExecutorService` - what do you mean by `automatic thread management`?

Comment: If i'm not mistaken, then in case a thread dies, it doesn't get replaced by the Executor. I was looking for a solution where the Executor keeps the thread pool staffed until the work is done.

At the same time, I'm not entirely sure, whether I should worry about threads dying in my case. And I still need to worry what to do with the work items when a thread dies between grabbing work and completing it. So, your example may be suitable for me after all.

Comment: [`Executors.newFixedThreadPool`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int)) manages fixed number of threads for you. As it mentioned in the javadoc `If any thread terminates due to a failure during execution prior to shutdown, a new one will take its place if needed to execute subsequent tasks.` Also, if you actually need "shrinkable"/"expandable" pool - [ExecutorService.newCachedThreadPool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool()) will be better choice.

Comment: "[...] if needed to execute subsequent tasks" -- in your example, the number of tasks (consumers.submit) is fixed at 10. The executor doesn't know about the actual tasks in the BlockingQueue

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by keeping actual work items in a BlockingQueue, but having producer submitting a notification task to the Executor, which directs a worker thread to drain the queue. When the notification tasks start to queue up, some workers will be able to get several work items from the BlockingQueue and some will get none, which is good enough for my batching purposes.